# What is the best way to save a RequestQueue response?

Tags: java, php, android

all. First time posting here.

Anyway, I wrote an Android method that creates a RequestQueue and sends a request to my server via a PHP script to get the server time. The way I have it DOES work, but I'm almost certain it's jury rigged code and there must be a better way to do it.

**Bottom Line:** I want to save the onResponse *response* into a String *time* that I can return (*time* was a String before being changed to an ArrayList). However, it won't let me use a String from outside onResponse unless it is final. Of course that means I can't change it to *response*.

I think I'm going about it wrong. Maybe there's a better way to get a response from the PHP script?

The Android method:

```
    public static String getServerTime(Context c){
    //Make a final ArrayList that will hold response once received
    final ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Set up the RequestQueue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(c);
    String requestUrl = c.getString(R.string.uploadServerUrl)+c.getString(R.string.serverRequestPath);
    Response.Listener responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() { @Override public void onResponse(String response) { time.add(response.toString()); System.out.println("onResponse: "+response.toString());}};
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() { @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {System.out.println("onErrorResponse: "+error.toString());}};
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, requestUrl, responseListener, errorListener){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("option", "0");
            return parameters;
        }
    };
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy(){
        @Override public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            return 50000;
        }
        @Override public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            return 50000;
        }
        @Override public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {}
    };
    request.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    requestQueue.add(request);
    return time.remove(0);
}
```

The PHP script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["option"])){
    $option = $_POST["option"];
    switch($option){

        case 0:
            date_default_timezone_set ("America/Chicago");
            $time = time();
            echo(date("Y;m;d;H;i;s", $time));


    }
}
    else{
        echo "No option set!";
    }
```

?>

Comment: Declare your String time variable as a field in the class - not as a variable inside method.

Comment: However the way you want this to work will never work - your method getServerTime will never return a time returned in onResponse because Volley request is asynchronous.

Comment: @Wukash Your suggestion worked. Thank you! 
I don't know how to use anything but Volley. What would you suggest I look into for something like this?

Comment: Volley is perfectly fine.